# Is there a programmatic way to designate an object as a document for Spring MongoDB besides annotations?

Tags: java, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I have a domain object library that is used by a number of services. One of those services would like to store an object in that library in an existing MongoDB collection which has a name that is different from the class name.

I would like to avoid adding the `@Document` annotation on the object in the domain object library because it would throw in a lot of unnecessary dependencies. Is there a programmatic way to set up my Mongo configuration such that if I call `MongoRepository.save()` on the object, it will know to save it in my collection?